# Source files customization for gulp.js task

Tags: gulp

I have a partial of my `gulpfile.js` as shown below

```
var paths = {
    src: {
        css: [
            'app/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', 
            'app/assets/highlight/styles/monokai_sublime.css'
            'app/assets/css/font.css',
            'app/assets/css/style.css', 
        ],
        js: [
            'app/assets/js/jquery.min.js',
            'app/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js',
            'app/assets/highlight/highlight.pack.js',
            'app/assets/js/script.js',
        ],
    },
    dest: {
        css: 'public/css/',
        js: 'public/js/',
    }
}

gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src(paths.src.css)
        // .pipe(autoprefixer())
        // .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest.css));
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src(paths.src.js)
        // .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(concat('script.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest.js));
});
```

For the **css** task I would like to perform `autoprefixer()` and `cssmin()` only for **some** source files then perform `concat()` for all of them into one single `style.css` and would like similarity to the **js** task, that only **some** source files need to be `uglify()` then `concat()` all of them into one single `script.js`

Comment: I presume you meant "source files"

Comment: Add files as needed into your gulp.src stream as required.